# PHP result from two arrays pairing dates where key is "Y"

Tags: php, arrays, date, arraylist

I have two array

```
$array1 = array("2017-12-08","2017-12-09","2017-12-10","2017-12-11","2017-12-12","2017-12-13","2017-12-14","2017-12-15","2017-12-16","2017-12-17","2017-12-18","2017-12-19","2017-12-20","2017-12-21","2017-12-22");
$array2 = array("Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","N","N","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N","Y","Y");
```

I need the first and last date where the key="Y". Like this:

```
$result = array("2017-12-08 - 2017-12-12", "2017-12-16 - 2017-12-18", "2017-12-21 - 2017-12-22");
```

How i can make this? 
I have tried with array_combine but after that I do not know how to list the dates pairing.

---

*Moved from answer*

> Yes this is a good idea, Justinas, but the result is not exactly what i need. Your result give me the first 2017-12-08 and the last 2017-12-22. But i need from all pairs the first and end date, like:

```
"2017-12-08 - 2017-12-12"
"2017-12-16 - 2017-12-18"
"2017-12-21 - 2017-12-22"
```

> Because i need to insert in the db like

```
INSERT INTO $table start='firstDate' AND end='lastDate'.
```

> And in this example 3 lines.

Comment: I not understand you question. I try to explain again a little better.

Answer (score 0):

First find only array keys that contains value as `Y`:

```
$yes = array_filter($array2, function ($yn) {return $yn == 'Y'});
```

Now do `$result = array_intersect_key($array1, $yes)` to get dates that has `Y` in array2.

Finally get first (`current($result)`) and last `end($result)` dates.

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3560e19434cd1a4dc08bcb86adcb9f852d7c3016)